# 2 column layout, how to get one column to match the others height with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Alright I have a not so uncommon layout, its a wrapper element with 2 columns floating side by side with `float:left` set on both columns. My problem isn't so much as getting either of the elements to line up with the bottom of the page. The problem is, when either element is larger than the page and exceeds the bounds of `100%` And even then its not so much a problem with both elements as it is I want the left hand element to stretch with the right hand element.

What I have so far is http://v2.newyorkbarshow.com

As you can see the element on the left already bleeds off the page, which is expected, not really desired but expected as its set to `height:100%;min-height:100%;` but it is also pushed down from the top by a margin as the header element is an absolute position element. In fact both the left and right hand sides are pushed down in the same mannor and both have the same height setting mentioned above. So the set themselves to the equivelant of what 100% should be had they not been pushed down by the margin. So like I said, undesired side effect but expected.

What you will also notice is in this example, the right side stretches further now, as there is content in it pushing it down. While the left side stays at its 100%, so I am wondering is there anyway to push that left column down to match in the event the right column stretches, or is this something I am either A) stuck with, or B need something other than CSS intervention to handle?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the following after the two columns

```
<div style="clear: both"></div>
```

Comment: Well, in a sense I think that works, but I have learned that my problem appears to be the content is overlapping the right side, as in staying within its bounds but once it reaches the bottom of that container it keeps on going without bring the container with it

Comment: @chris - put it into fiddle.

Comment: the whole html, css, and everything?

Comment: Enough to demonstrate the problem. No more and no less.

Comment: @chris - Would it be possible to have a sketch of what you are expecting?

Comment: if you go to the fiddle you will notice the green column on the left, if you go to my original link in the post you will see an example of that with a body of content included (not in the fiddle), but in general what my aim, hope, goal would be is to have that green column meet the bottom of the page where the content ends, rather than where `100%` would be otherwise

Comment: not only would I want it to meet the bottom based on content, but on other pages as they come into play, will have way less content so I still want the green column to extend to the bottom of the page. I know overall the problem is css related or I would like to think it is, but Im not 100% sure about that.

Comment: @chris - There is no green column - do you mean the yellow (goldish) one?

Comment: @chris - It is usually a good idea to avoid specifying the height.

Comment: Heres a screen shot, with an arrow as to what I reference as the green column. http://i1355.photobucket.com/albums/q710/chrishacia/Screen-Shot-2012-11-09-at-35609-AM.png

Comment: It is not green - It is dark blue. Guess you are colour blind. Will have a peek later but off to lunch.

Comment: Actually, its Teal:  somewhere between green and blue.